# Plotting C5.0 Tree in R

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a C5.0 object tree in R but it is giving the following error and I can't seem to find out how to fix it.

```
plot(model)

Error in partysplit(varid = as.integer(i), index = index, info = k, prob = NULL)   : 
 minimum of ‘index’ is not equal to 1
In addition: Warning message:
In min(index, na.rm = TRUE) :
 no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the factors in your data frame contain spaces. I was facing the same issue, then I removed spaces from them and now it works.
for example, if a variable has factors " bad" and " good" then change them to "bad" and "good".

*"The error itself is due to NA values being passed in the index vector. The root cause is probably that the factor levels are being split on spaces*" Found here https://github.com/topepo/C5.0/issues/10

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
library(rattle)
fancyRpartPlot(model)
```